# Ember.js Component didRender Variable Scope

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using an Ember Component's `didRender()` hook to implement some javascript that needs to run after the DOM is loaded. For Example:

```
didRender() {
  var signaturePad = new SignaturePad($("#sigElement"));
  signaturePad.clear();
}
```

This is working fine. However, I need to access the `signaturePad` variable from my actions in the same component to have buttons function appropriately. Such as:

```
actions: {
   clearSignature: function() {
     signaturePad.clear();
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems my variable defined in the `didRender()` hook for the component does not pass to the `actions`.

How am I able to access this variable from my actions within the same component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do a something just after loading DOM, you should use `didInsertElement` hook.

And creating a variable does not set that as propert to use after in another situation.

Please change like this :

```
didInsertElement() {
  var signaturePad = new SignaturePad($("#sigElement"));
  signaturePad.clear();
  this.set('signaturePad', signaturePad);
}

actions: {
   clearSignature: function() {
     this.get('signaturePad').clear();
   }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!